# travelocity example wso2

Tags: jsp, wso2, xacml, identityserver2

I'm new to wso2 IS and I'm following [Configuring Access Control Policy for a Service Provider](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Access+Control+Policy+for+a+Service+Provider)  tutorial to implement an XACML policy.

Everything works fine and I have followed the tutorial strictly. But as soon as I follow last step and hit the url, everything works fine, but I can not find the username and password field to test my policy.

[image: page shown to me]

Comment: You can click on the "click here to login with saml from wso2". It will prompt the WSO2 login page